# Can't get Babel to compile with the "polyfill" plugin

Tags: babeljs

I can't seem to get my scripts to compile with Babel. I have installed **@babel/polyfill**

```
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

That gives me:

```
babel /home/xxx/public_html/2018/js/lib/cat-ajax-scroll.js > /home/xxx/public_html/2018/js/lib-non-es6/cat-ajax-scroll.js

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN lib@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN lib@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @babel/polyfill@7.7.0
updated 1 package and audited 6852 packages in 4.279s
```

Then when I look in the node_modules folder, I correctly see /js/lib/node_modules/@babel/polyfill with all the files in

My **.bablerc** looks like:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/polyfill"
   ]
}
```

Yet when I run the compiler I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-polyfill' from '/home/xxx/public_html/2018/js/lib'
- If you want to resolve "@babel/polyfill", use "module:@babel/polyfill"
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:74:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:54:10)
    at loadPlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:62:20)
    at createDescriptor (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPluginDescriptors (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:105:10)
    at plugins (/usr/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:40:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

I'm not sure what else to try :/